# Trying to get one step closer to the understanding of free energies $F$ and $G$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, reversibility

I find it quite hard to get a good grasp of the notions of Helmoltz and Gibbs free energy, because they can be introduced in so many different ways, and embody so many different ideas at once...

Here, i would like to look at the "available energy picture". In this website (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/helmholtz.html), they propose an interesting interpretation of F as being the energy required to create as system on its own minus the energy that an environment at constant temperature naturally givesas heat during the creation.

this is quite a similar idea that I had of enthalpy H=U+PV, being the energy required to create a system on its own + the PV energy required to make room for it in an environment at constant pressure

**My actual question is the following : for H, under the right conditions (P=cst + reversible),it enabled us, after straight-forward math, to write deltaH=Q. We could get rid of the PV work term because it was already included in the very definition of H ! (for these particular conditions of course)
Does that mean that with F we can get rid of the heat transferred in a similar fashion, when dealing with a reversible process at constant T (something  like deltaF=Wrev because "Q is already included in the defintion of F ?")**

If yes, I will probably want to extend the question with related considerations about G and reversible work, but we can already see that first point before, in order to avoid a mess :)

Comment: How they are defined in physics is quite clear. How you grasp them or your intuition about them is a personal thing that may not be (is not) transferable from person to person.

Comment: Of course. But still, the question I asked is answerable, isn't it ?

Comment: Well, I'd step back and relate each of (F, G, H) to their independent variables. If you mess with (S, p) you get H; (T, V) gets F; (T, p) gets you G. Those then give you, as a result, pictures like you link propose, but they are an outcome of what thermodynamic variables you have chosen as your 'basis'. Whether that helps you or anybody else (or not) is what makes it personal.